# How to install psycopg2 from source?

Tags: python, postgresql

I'm able to install the newest psycopg2 from the source but it's doesn't work for 2.8.6
Command: `sudo pip3 install --no-binary :all: psycopg2==2.8.6`
Output: `Skipping wheel build for psycopg2, due to binaries being disabled for it.`
I'm not a python dev, need to prepare production server and the documentation states I should not use binary driver for the prod. Is it ok to leave it as it?

Comment: It should be ok.  If you run pip with the `--verbose` flag you should see the compiler output from gcc.

Comment: But the installation is so fast thus I believe it installs the binary, for 2.9.x it takes a while and I can see compiler output

Comment: It works for me here. In other words `pip3 install --no-binary :all: psycopg2==2.8.6` installs from source.